# "I'm not a leaker"

Tags: traduction

Figuratively, *to leak* translates into French as *divulguer*.

But how can I say *leaker* as in the by now famous phrase *I'm not a leaker!*?

Is it *divulguereur*?

Comment: First, you'd have to say "divulgueur".  But it's not used.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Dans le contexte actuel on emploie de plus en plus le mot ***fuiteur***.

> WikiLeaks et Snowden font partie d'une nouvelle force non gouvernementale, celle des fuiteurs sans frontières.(*Le Monde*,[1.7.2013](http://www.lemonde.fr/idees/article/2013/07/01/fuiteurs-sans-frontieres_3439292_3232.html))

> le président américain a qualifié M.Comey de "fuiteur" (*La Tribune*,[9.06.2017](http://www.latribune.fr/economie/international/l-ex-directeur-du-fbi-dresse-un-requisitoire-implacable-contre-trump-735032.html))

Le mot *fuiteur* ne se trouve pas encore dans tous les dictionnaires, alors certains disent volontiers « l'auteur de la fuite ». Le nom *fuite* est par contre couramment employé.

> James Comey avoue avoir lui-même organisé, après son limogeage par Donald Trump, les fuites à la presse de notes sur ses rencontres avec le président américain (*La Croix*, le [08/06/2017](http://www.la-croix.com/Monde/Ameriques/EN-DIRECT-Suivez-laudition-James-Comey-lex-directeur-FBI-2017-06-08-1200853481))

Le verbe associé est *fuiter*, surtout dans le contexte de l'information et de la politique, on peut employer *divulguer*, par contre  « divulguereur » n'existe pas.

> Donald Trump accuse le FBI de laisser fuiter des informations. (LES ECHOS | [Le 24/02/17](https://www.lesechos.fr/24/02/2017/lesechos.fr/0211829374763_donald-trump-accuse-le-fbi-de-laisser-fuiter-des-informations.htm))

Answer (score 4):

You could say "Je ne suis pas une balance", from the verb "balancer". This may be seem as argotic and should not be used in a professional environment, though.

Comment: +1 C'est bien le mot que j'utiliserais sur  un T-shirt avec la tête de Comey.